# How translate to Spanish the message Today in Filter date of Kendo Angular UI

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

The change language of Kendo is running, and the dates are translated, but the message of "Today", is in English, but i like it in Spanish "Hoy", Thanks...

Comment: Please, can you give us more details ? Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

check messages.es-* js file and extend it or override with missing messages.